# How to change legend marker size in C3?

Tags: d3.js, svg, c3.js

I'm trying to change the size of legend marker in C3. In C3 documentation there is nothing about being able to do that, so I'm trying with css.
As far as I can see, legend marker is a `<line>` tag in svg. So the only thing I can change is stroke properties. If I change stroke-width, I get "higher" marker, but of the same width. Changing stroke-linecap also didn't do the trick.
Is changing marker size possible?

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yIZ8kFhlWV7v7LY0mXdL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change directly in c3.js (c3.min.js), in function c3_chart_internal_fn.getDefaultConfig().

From

```
legend_item_tile_width: 10,
legend_item_tile_height: 10,
```

to

```
legend_item_tile_width: 16,
legend_item_tile_height: 16,
```

Comment: Is there some way to do this without changing directly in c3.js? This generally seems like a bad idea...

Comment: I agree, but at the time of writing this there was no other option for changing these values. One of the reasons I switched back to d3. Maybe in the last year and a half (since I had this problem) some new version added the possibility, I don't know.